# Setting the time

Tags: code-golf, date

Imagine the following 24-hour clock that can be controlled by arrow keys:

```
╔══╗ ┌──┐
║00║:│00│
╚══╝ └──┘
 HH   mm
```

Pressing the up arrow twice (`↑↑`) will increase the currently focused hour input:

```
╔══╗ ┌──┐
║02║:│00│
╚══╝ └──┘
 HH   mm
```

Pressing the right arrow (`→`) will focus the other input.

```
┌──┐ ╔══╗
│02│:║00║
└──┘ ╚══╝
 HH   mm
```

Pressing the down arrow thrice (`↓↓↓`) will now decrease this input.

```
┌──┐ ╔══╗
│02│:║57║
└──┘ ╚══╝
 HH   mm
```

Shortly put:

- The up arrow (`↑`) will increase the currently active input.
- The down arrow (`↓`) will decrease the active input.
- The right arrow (`→`) will move focus to the right input.
- The left arrow (`←`) will move focus to the left input.
- Up and down movement will loop around as expected for a time input.
- Left and right movement don't loop around.

### The challenge

The clock starts out at `00:00` with the hour input active (see first schematic). Given a list of input commands, output the resulting time in `HH:mm` format.
Input can be either a string or a list (or your language equivalent), where the different input directions can be one of the below options:

- `↑↓←→`
- `udlr`
- `^v<>`
- actual arrow key presses if your program has a GUI

Standard loopholes apply.

### Test cases

```
↑↑→↓↓↓ = 02:57
↓→↑←↑→↓ = 00:00
↓→→↓ = 23:59
←←←←→↑ = 00:01
↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓→↓ = 23:59
```

Comment: Does one have to use the four specified input direction to value mappings or can one freely choose four different unique values?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/138254/58974)

Comment: @JonathanFrech One of the given options, choosing any four unique values (for example `0123`) would make the challenge a lot easier in certain languages while not benefitting others.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Yes, that's actually written out under the input rules.

Comment: @Arnauld What about `(h+24e9)%24` which works in practice but not in theory?

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for the idea, added.

Comment: @l4m2 Given that it would require an input string of ~22 GB to make it fail, I'd personally say that's an acceptable hack.

Comment: I think this would have been more challenging if it included seconds. This would have more logic behind which one is currently in focus

Comment: Missing a special rule to handle Konami code.

Comment: @coredump Considered it, but it would probably take more space than the core of the answer in most languages.

Answer (score 40):

## HTML on Google Chrome 67 in Chinese (Simplified), 39 bytes

```html
<input type=time value=00:00 autofocus>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Chrome show different UI component in different language. Even a simple time input: AM/PM will be shown if you are using English (US). If you want test this by changing your Chrome's language. Do not mass up how to change it back.

Comment: dudee!! hahah I think is not valid tho

Comment: Hitting right twice goes to `AM/PM` for me

Comment: @JoKing I think it's locale/settings dependent?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Why invalid?

Comment: as @JoKing said, hitting twice goes to `AM/PM`

Comment: @tsh You can save one byte by omitting the closing `>`, the browser will figure it out.

Comment: @Nit not such, tested, not working...

Comment: @tsh Works on my Chrome, what version are you running?

Comment: @JoKing That's locale dependent. Maybe have a try by changing your Chrome's language to Chinese Simplify? (Do not mass up how to change it back.)

Comment: @JoKing, no such problem in Russia. You have to change your locale to 24-hour instead of 12-hour.

Comment: It works on firefox 61.0.1

Comment: This answer is pretty similar to the [AHK answer in another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158202/69850).

Comment: @FranciscoHahn My Firefox ask me for AM/PM. That's why I claim it as Chrome.

Answer (score 13):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>117</s> 107 bytes

- Saved ten bytes thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2).

```c
t,i,m[8];e(char*_){for(*m=i=2[m]=0;t=*_++;t<63?i=t%4:(i[m]+=t&8?1:'w'));printf("%02d:%02d",*m%24,2[m]%60);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzPDoIgAMbP9RSOjQKkzcw5J6IP4sQ50uKANSM6OJ@dsFvzO3yH3/dHnm5SOmeoorrOGtYjee8m0uJ5eEyIaK54XOuGR8xw0oYhM0V6qRQ3MMmR8knIzSGrzvnxc8SYPSc1mgEBGMXXfDVAiYZxQtcTmEaYLU53akR43u96BIQorbUg8Mu3eSEAMPtxW4rCR2DLPQyCTb/wKsX/z@K@)

Comment: Nice variable naming.

Comment: # [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 107 bytes

<!-- language-all: lang-c -->

   ```t,i,m[8];e(char*_){for(*m=i=2[m]=0;t=*_++;t<63?i=t%4:(i[m]+=t&8?1:119));printf("%02d:%02d",*m%24,2[m]%60);}```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzPDoIgAMbP9RSOjQZIm5pzJqIP4sQ50uKANSMuzmcn7Nb8Dt/h9/2R57uUzhmqqG7ylg1IPvqZdHgZnzMimiueNLrlETOcdGHITJldasUNTAukfBJyc8rruIjjK8bsNavJjAjAKLkVmwFKNExSup3ALMJsdbpXE8LL8TAgIERlrQWBX37MGwGA2Y/bSpQ@AnvuYRDs@qVXJf5/VvcF)

Answer (score 6):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>36</s> <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 32 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
áXò↑─↨√▓|êóÇiU&≡Q#┤Æ⌡⌠╟C▐╜√⌡∟▄╩╠
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a0589518c417fbb27c88a280695526f05123b492f5f4c743debdfbf51cdccacc&i=uurddd%0Adrulurd%0Adrrd%0Allllru%0Adddddddddddddddddddddddddrd&a=1&m=2)

Uses `lrud`.

Explanation:

```
'l/{'r/Bs$2lmM{${:14-m|+i36*24+%2|zm':* Full program,
'l/                                     Split the string on "l"
   {        m                           Map over the resulting array
    'r/                                   Split at "r"
       B                                  Uncons left, first on TOS (top of stack)
        s                                 Swap to get tail to top
         $                                Flatten; this removes multiple 'r's
          2l                              Listify two items, BOS (bottom of stack) is first element
             M                          Transpose: get [hour commands, minute commands]
              {                    m    Map:
               $                          Flatten
                {    m                    Map over single commands:
                 :1                         Number of set bits: 5 for 'u', 3 for 'd'
                   4-                       Subtract 4: u -> 1, d -> -1
                      |+                  Sum
                        i                 Iteration index: hours -> 0, minutes -> 1
                         36*24+           Multiply by 36, add 24: 0 -> 24, 1 -> 60
                               %          Modulo, this does -5 % 60 = 55
                                2|z       Stringify, left-padding with "0" to length 2
                                    ':* Join on ":"
                                        Implicit output
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 105 bytes

```python
h=m=p=0
for c in map(' ^<>'.find,input()):w=1/c;m+=w*p;h+=w-w*p;p=[c-2,p][w]
print'%02d:%02d'%(h%24,m%60)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BDoMgGIPvPAUhIajTzZltBxVexIxkQQ0cwD/G4fb0DLyvh/Zr0qTw3fTimqCWceKEkKC55cBrNC8rVtg4bF@QMSx7wc6zcWNpHLy3LM/bnV8vqrMnvhfQ6RhVAuCDqpoSnsP@RLAatzFaN2ObjNFM0@ZWWvqo8xDf0PSZFE7fxT0QKYX3niDihewjH3REHyVk6v8UZz8)

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>149</strike> 132 bytes

```cs
s=>{var p=0;int[]h={0,0};foreach(var c in s)h[p=c<63?c/2%2:p]+=c>62?c>95?-1:1:0;return$"{(h[0]%24+24)%24:D2}:{(h[1]%60+60)%60:D2}";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9Na4NAGITv/ooXaUAxH@umsWT9yKGlpxYKPfQgCrIxcSFdw@5GCOJvt2s0JD0EnMvA7LsPM1TOaCnylh4yKeHLqA3QkipTjILIs23JD2f4PkuV/87fT5wGUgnG91PoPYIdhK0Mo7rKBBxD5DOu4qQIazRFjb/T7IwWVvdIgXGQdhEfQxp4yw1d4Akmx8QJaeThDY3Wq83MJS5BvsjVSfAns7aKGCUT/OzgZ1sbecMN6UI3mXjI8ZCtrQtNv2lhkG/cb6hKtoXPjHGrLxwnkIm9tC83/dpOw8LXksvykM9/BFP5B@O5ZaZpVFUVQAgmOLC7BqZt@wCLBSBMVi8jOFWUBvrnjTMEF1DHQQShURwNAbjnDBC49MFLslqP4ARaUXrH6YPbLt3HHdPnkf5tfXx03X/r3RiN0f4B)

Using `^v<>`.

This one made me realize that the modulo operator in C# does not work as expected, because in C# `-1 % 60 = -1`, so I need to do that weird operation at the end.

Comment: Can't (h[1]%60+60)%60 be replaced with (h[1]+60)%60 ?

Comment: @IanF1 no you can't. What if the user presses the down button 100 times? Or 1000 times?

Comment: thanks for clarifying :) it's surprising to me that this way is shorter than applying the modulo on the fly (with 59 in place of -1).

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 103 bytes

Takes input as a string, using `udlr`.

```javascript
s=>(Buffer(s).map(n=>n%6?s%4?m+=n%2||59:h+=n%2||23:s=n,h=m=0),g=n=>('0'+n).slice(-2))(h%24)+':'+g(m%60)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBNDoIwEAXgvadg03QmCNYqGptUE29CKD@aUkhrXXl3rFE3KLxVk@mXN5lrfs9dYS/9LTGdKodKDk4e4eyrqrTgMG3zHow8GrI7ObI9tbE0hD8e2UE0nyffCCfNspGtZLisZfgNlNHYYOr0pSgh4YjQEL7FmAoa19CSHcOh6IzrdJnqroYKKEWMZrJaRYwJxhYj5r1VStFoQr8YF9l@zJT1Okg6w/61KRtMmE@zcI3sMGY6xPrZJUPb@qdtKu/Fv23DEw)

Answer (score 5):

**Lua (love2d framework),<strike>311</strike> 308 bytes**

```
l,b,d,t,f,a=love,{24,60},{1,-1},{0,0},1,{"left","right","up","down"}function c(n,i)t[f]=(n+d[i])%b[f]end function l.draw()h,m=t[1],t[2]l.graphics.print((h<10 and 0 ..h or h)..":"..(m<10 and 0 ..m or m),0,0)end function l.keypressed(k)for i,n in pairs(a)do f=k==n and(i>2 and(c(t[f],i-2)or f)or i)or f end end
```

Unscrumbeled version:

```
--initialize all needed values
l,b,d,t,f,a=love,{24,60},{1,-1},{0,0},1,{"left","right","up","down"}

--increase the numbers depending on the focus and up or down
function c(n,i)
  t[f]=(n+d[i])%b[f]
end 

--draw the time to the screen
function l.draw()
  h,m=t[1],t[2]
  l.graphics.print((h<10 and 0 ..h or h)..":"..(m<10 and 0 ..m or m),0,0)
end

--get the keys and check if it is an arrow key
function l.keypressed(k)
  for i,n in pairs(a)do
    f=k==n and(i>2 and(c(t[f],i-2)or f)or i)or f 
  end 
end
```

Probably still not 100% easy to read because all the ifs are interchanged
    with an  trinary statement   ( ..and ..or) :)

if started in an main.lua with love  then it will pop up a window and you can press the arrowkeys to change the numbers

Comment: could you also post expanded version for readability

Comment: sure, I added a expanded version no problem :)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](http://www.php.net/), <s>145</s> <s>134</s> 133 bytes

(-11 bytes by more golfing)

(-1 byte by using [Davіd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78488/dav%d1%96d)'s loop method)

```php
<?for($h=$m=0,$a=h;$c=$argv[++$i];)$c<l?$$a--:($c>r?$$a++:$a=$c<r?h:m);$h%=24;$m%=60;printf('%02d:%02d',$h<0?$h+24:$h,$m<0?$m+60:$m);
```

To run it:

```
php -n -d error_reporting=0 <filename> <command_1> <command_2> ... <command_n>
```

Example:

```
php -n -d error_reporting=0 time_setter.php u u r d d d l d
```

Or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvbCoMwGINfZRcRlSoUES9auz7IGEM8VVgP/HN7/P3T8UFISJJcYu7tEqmAM/BGVhiM0xgNBlo/NyGw3XWJsX9aYKhrVWC80umFUMf2aMg65UsNl5mm1fCZ6aROtIV9KfJMNpM6Ja/gemnhRNMquAr@TF50UuF4M/P7gHj68@TpG9O@xfDiOnA9XWaiSA@aU6R9C6uRPw)

**Notes:**

- To save some bytes, I have used strings without single/double quotations as the string wrapper. Thus, the `error_reporting=0` option is used to not output warnings.
- Input commands: `u d l r`

Comment: 128 bytes, -6: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtRCoMwEESv0o8VIzEQRPyIpjlIKUWMmoAmYWt7/G6jDAzDm5nkEtFglogMdi1rGLXrYdIw4vp9cA7@2VcwDZsBGIVQDKY7nplzlbe5QePUXvUJfTgWVhayseq0smbgCt201SANON60Clxme6E7ebGdd1JB/hLRJwvJXtrI/mI6fAxvEoGEvc2IEV84p4iHD6uWfw) (Nice solution, btw :)

Comment: @Davіd: Thanks, but your update has two issues. First on is that $h is not set, so decreasing it on start fails: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvbCoMwEER/pQ8rRmIgiPgQk@ZDSiniLYHmwir9/G5jX4bhnJnsMpG2W0IGwcgWJuNGmA1MuH8enIN/jg3M@m0BJiEUg/mOV@dclW0xaJ0KzZjRx3NjdSW7RV1RtwxcZbq@0dKC412vwBUWKjPIPwt8kArKl4iWb8qnT/EgEUkstxUx4QvXnPD0cTfyBw "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @David: And the second issue happens when we switch hour/minute up or down more than 24/60 times: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lYtdCoMwEISv0ocVIzEQRHyIpjlIKUWMmkDzw1Z6/G5jb1AGhuGbmewy0WS2hAyCli3M2o2waJhxf984B38fG1impwGYhVAMliuemXNVtqVB41Roxow@HhurK9lZdVrdMnCV7vpmkgYc73oFrrBQ6UH@WOCDVFC@RGT/FpL9pHz4FF8kIgl7WRETPnDNCQ8fdy2/ "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @Davіd: But thanks to your loop method, I could reduce 1 more byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvbCoMwGINfZRcRlSoUES9auz7IGEM8VVgP/HN7/P3T8UFISJJcYu7tEqmAM/BGVhiM0xgNBlo/NyGw3XWJsX9aYKhrVWC80umFUMf2aMg65UsNl5mm1fCZ6aROtIV9KfJMNpM6Ja/gemnhRNMquAr@TF50UuF4M/P7gHj68@TpG9O@xfDiOnA9XWaiSA@aU6R9C6uRPw "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: ah, alright, sorry it didn't completely work :)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>104</s> 103 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters, using `<>^v`.

```
a=>(a.map(z=>z<"^"?a=z<">":a?x+=z<"v"||23:y+=z<"v"||59,x=y=0),g=n=>`0${n}`.slice(-2))(x%24)+`:`+g(y%60)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dY5NCoMwFIT3HiNUSFCD2B@o9T0PIoYEq2KxKlWCWnt2m1rorrOZ@YZZzE1p1WePqhu8pr3mawGrAqSK31VHZ8A5IoLECowjCVU8Op@oybIE@3D6wfHsjjCBz9wSGkDp757NS/K@rrKcegFjdLSDA3NkKJ2STvbJZ@sAiUWEQK01cS2iUUQGvvHrkRGKrfknM7TSy7DdrQCztunbOud1W9KCJpzzKmWMrW8)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL),  <s>57</s>  <s>56</s>  55 bytes

```
1Oi9\"@5<?y@3-ZS*+}wx7@-X^w]]wx&Zjh24 60h\'%02d:%02d'YD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N/QP9MyRsnB1Ma@0sFYNypYS7u2vMLcQTcirjw2trxCLSorw8hEwcwgI0Zd1cAoxQpEqEe6/HcJ@a8eF2dXVlamzqVeZhdnA2SDWWDKBgjs4kB8XACoDAA)

Represents hour and minutes using complex numbers, with the real part being hours and the imaginary part minutes.

#### With comments:

```
1     % Push 1 on the stack
      % represents which timer box we're in, starts at hour box
      % imaginary number j would represent minutes box
O     % Push initial hour and minutes 0+0j
i9\   % Fetch input, mod each character's ASCII value by 9.
      % Gives 4 1 8 6 for ^ v > < respectively
"     % iterate through (modded) input
  @5<?     % Push current input, see if it's < 5 
           % if so, it's an up or down time change
    y        % so copy out the box indicator (1 or j)
    @3-      % Subtract 3 from the current input
    ZS       % Take the result's sign (-1 for v, 1 for ^)
    *        % Multiply indicator with that
    +        % Add the result to the time value
  }        % else, it's a right or left arrow
    wx       % so bring out the box indicator and delete it
    7@-      % Subtract current input from 7. 1 for < and -1 for >
    X^       % Take the square root of that. 1 for < and j for >
    w        % switch stack to bring time value on top again
  ]       % end if
]     % end loop
wx    % bring box indicator out, delete it
&Zj   % split the complex time value to real and imaginary
h     % then concatenate them into an array
24 60h\ % mod hour and minute values by 24 and 60 respectively
'%02d:%02d'YD % sprintf the time array with 0-padding
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 236 bytes

```
f=u 0 0
k _ _ _ _ _ h m[]=z h++':':z m
k a b c d e h m(q:s)=case q of{'^'->e(a h)(b m)s;'v'->e(c h)(d m)s;'>'->v h m s;'<'->u h m s}
u=k(o(+)24)id(o(-)24)id u
v=k id(o(+)60)id(o(-)60)v
o f m x=mod(f x 1)m
z n|n<10='0':show n
z n=show n
```

`f` is the main function, and has type `String -> String`:

```
*Main> f "^^>vvv"
"02:57"
*Main> f "v>^<^>v"
"00:00"
*Main> f "v>>v"
"23:59"
*Main> f "<<<<>^"
"00:01"
*Main> f "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv>v"
"23:59"
```

Essentially `u` and `v` are mutually recursive functions of type `Integer -> Integer -> String -> String`. They take the hour, the minute and a list of characters over the set `{v,^,<,>}`, and return the time string. `u` acts as if the hour dial is highlighted, recursively calling `u` if the head of the list is in `{v,^}`, and `v` if the head of the list is in `{<,>}`. `v` is similar but for the minute dial.

Everything else is just saving characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 132 bytes

```lua
loadstring's,t,m=1,{0,0},{24,60}for c in(...):gmatch"."do t[s]=(t[s]+(("d u"):find(c)or 2)-2)%m[s]s=("lr"):find(c)or s end return t'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9BCsIwELz7iiUgJpiGGsRDIS@RHmLTarBNZJPiQXx7TFRED85hlt1hZnfHWadBpdFrEyJad1wFHvmkNvxW8/rOb3LLd/V98AgdWEeFEKw5Tjp2JyKI8RD3oVW08JpSYmAmrBmsM7Rj2SNZJdlyympQlIz4IwbonQHs44wO4ipZL65oY59zlrU0TaFi8Jj30agPYy9md9HdmQ7PQzIWVQUem1IQFLzmpfuEvd4S75SvZI77TZtJtiwl8w9oHg)

---

#### Explanation

This is an anonymous function (a way  to use it is shown on the link).

```lua
s=1 -- s will control the selection (1 is hour and 2 min)
t={0,0} -- is the time itself
m={24,60} -- is the maximum for each 'box' (hour or min)
-- I've actually used Lua's multiple variable assignment: s,t,m=1,{0,0},{24,60}

for c in (...):gmatch(".") do -- go through each character of the input
  t[s] = (t[s] + (("d u"):find(c) or 2)-2) % m[s] -- set the current 'box' as
          t[s] +   -- itself plus ...
                  ("d u"):find(c) or 2   -- it's index on the string "d u" (that means it's going to be 1 or 3)
                                         -- or 2 if it wasn't found (if the current character doesn't sum or subtract from the box)
                                       -2   -- this adjusts the result 1, 2 or 3 to being -1, 0 or 1
                                            -- making the inputs 'd' and 'u' as -1 and +1 respectively, and an input different from both as 0
         (                               ) % m[s]   -- modulo of the maximum of the selected 'box'

  s=("lr"):find(c) or s
    ("lr"):find(c)   -- if the current input character is l or r, then set 's' (the 'box' selection) to being 1 or 2.
                   or s   -- else let it as is
end
return t -- returns 't', a table with hour and minutes respectively
```

Comment: The output should be in the `HH:mm` format, rather than a table

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>101 91 89</s> 86 bytes

```perl6
{$/=[];$!=0;$_>2>($!=$_-3)||($/[$!]+=$_-1)for .ords X%5;($0%24,$1%60).fmt("%02d",":")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYvBCoJAFEX3fcU4vIkZMh2tXDTodwQiErxmNWI8m4Vk3z5ZEOiiu7rnXO79Rq4I3ci2lpUsPCEt68ZAVGoDbZVXcq7Q7g9qmiSkNUTN7sOZsj2xpCcc2EWcjAQt8mMMmSi0Smz3kFzoHHnMz1y9wnAdmZXcoyOuzOaHnhBxIZC8m93KrNDNIb/c/@V7C28)

Anonymous code block that takes a string of `uldr` characters and returns in the given format

Answer (score 2):

## [QBasic](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack), 229 bytes

A script that takes input as keystrokes and outputs to the console.

*Note: terminal `"` are included for syntax highlighting only, and do not contribute to the bytecount*

```vb
z$=CHR$(0)
DO
x=0
y=0
SELECT CASE INKEY$
CASE z$+"K"
r=0
CASE z$+"M"
r=1
CASE z$+"H"
x=1
y=1
CASE z$+"P"
x=23
y=59
END SELECT
IF r THEN m=(m+y)MOD 60ELSE h=(h+x)MOD 24
CLS
?RIGHT$("00000"+LTRIM$(STR$(h*1000+m)),5)
LOCATE 1,3
?":"
LOOP
```

#### Commented

```vb
z$=CHR$(0)                                      ''  Set var to null char
DO                                              ''
    x=0                                         ''  Set Hours Shift to 0 
    y=0                                         ''  Set Minutes Shift to 0 
    SELECT CASE INKEY$                          ''  Take keystroke input
        CASE z$+"K"                             ''  If is Left Arrow
            r=0                                 ''    Bool to modify right (minutes) 
        CASE z$+"M"                             ''  If is Right Arrow
            r=1                                 ''    Bool to modify left (hours)
        CASE z$+"H"                             ''  If is Up Arrow
            x=1                                 ''    Set Hours Shift to 1 
            y=1                                 ''    Set Minutes Shift to 1
        CASE z$+"P"                             ''  If is Down Arrow
            x=23                                ''    Set Hours Shift to 23 
            y=59                                ''    Set Minutes Shift to 23 
    END SELECT                                  ''
    IF r THEN m=(m+y)MOD 60ELSE h=(h+x)MOD 24   ''  Shift Minutes If `r=1` Else Shift Hours
    CLS                                         ''  Clear Screen
    ?RIGHT$("00000"+LTRIM$(STR$(h*1000+m)),5)   ''  Use math to concat Hours and Minutes 
                                                ''  then Convert to String and prepend 0s 
                                                ''  to a length of 5
    LOCATE 1,3                                  ''  Cursor to the the third digit
    ?":"                                        ''  Overwrite that digit with a `:`
LOOP                                            ''  Loop
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(m+y)`?

Comment: In the note, should not _does_ be _do_?

Comment: @JonathanFrech - Yep it should be. Thanks for keeping my grammar in check

Comment: Sorry, I thought `m` was for minutes for some reason... I see your commented version is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 121 bytes

```java
c->{int i=0,m[]={0,0,0};for(int t:c)if(t<63)i=t%4;else m[i]+=(t&8)>0?1:119;return"".format("%02d:%02d",m[0]%24,m[2]%60);}
```

Port of [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech)'s C [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168794/79343). Accepts `^v<>`. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##lZBda4MwFIav9VcEwZGw1kb7sVWrY/S6V7ssClmadmn9Ih6FUvztLtrBrkrbN3AOHHKevG@OrGHjohT5cXfqyvo7lRzxlFUV2jCZo4tpyByE2jMu0Dot@KkfGV@gZH5AIDOB@Q9T2xjJvKyhIoFptKbxB6qAgW5NIXco0zh83dO3mTpUZEBdoXyoIer4OLroF5EM6SjbxuGFjvRpg32hcD8HnxO5x7BaTIkMwZ4FIq0EyrYyfg0xvLyTiH64vusuAyWgVrllOXo3Y4Atm3o7vy@WRtPY9ma6e7G9oCRoO8MI@mTnCkTmFDU4pfYKaY4Hb86Q1UqSqGkay4FirWN/KsXOmBASoFuaTBD1/PnbfXQTJStNf5zdo6lP6SPoZ7hXtDf158v76JVWlDz5Idq1@4DrW7oV5t91a7bdLw).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>I believe `O%5;4ṣ3œṡ€4Z%3’§§%"“ð<‘DŻ€ṫ€-j”:` should work for 32, but `œṡ` [seems to currently have a bug](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45712592#45712592).</sup>

```
O%5;4ṣ3i€4$œṖ"$Z%3’§§%"“ð<‘DŻ€ṫ€-j”:
```

A full program printing the result to STDOUT (as a monadic link it actually returns a mixed list of integers (albeit single digit ones) and characters (the `:`).

Uses the `udlr` option for input.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99f1dTa5OHOxcaZj5rWmKgcnfxw5zQllShV40cNMw8tP7RcVelRw5zDG2weNcxwObobqObhztVAUjfrUcNcq////@dAQQqcTskpgsEUqgAA)** Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99f1dTa5OHOxcaZj5rWmKgcnfxw5zQllShV40cNMw8tP7RcVelRw5zDG2weNcxwObobqObhztVAUjfrUcNcq/8Pd2853A7kRv7/X1palJKSwpVSVJoDZAFpIJEDBEWlXCm4QFEKAA).

#### How?

```
O%5;4ṣ3i€4$œṖ"$Z%3’§§%"“ð<‘DŻ€ṫ€-j”: - Link: list of characters (in 'udlr')
O                                    - to ordinals
 %5                                  - modulo five  ...maps u:2, d:0, l:3, r:4
   ;4                                - concatenate a 4 (to always end up with both hrs & mins - even when no r is ever pressed)
     ṣ3                              - split at threes (the l presses)
       i€4$œṖ"$                      - a replacement for œṡ€4 (split each at first occurrence of)...
              $                      - | last two links as a monad:
          $                          - |   last two links as a monad:
         4                           - |     literal four
       i€                            - |     for €ach get first index of (4) else yield 0
             "                       - |   zip with:
           œṖ                        - |     partition at indices
               Z                     - transpose (to get a list of two lists of lists)
                %3                   - modulo by three. To replace any 4(r) with 1
                                     -  ...while keeping any 0(d) as 0, or 2(u) as 2
                  ’                  - decrement. All r are now 0, d are -1 and u are 1
                   §                 - sum each
                    §                - sum each. Now we have the total increase value as
                                     -    ...integers for each of hrs and mins
                       “ð<‘          - code-page indices list = [24,60]
                      "              - zip with:
                     %               -   modulo
                           D         - to decimal lists
                            Ż€       - prepend each with a zero (to cater for values less than ten)
                              ṫ€-    - tail each from index -1. Keeps rightmost two digits of each only)
                                  ”: - literal character ':'
                                 j   - join
                                     - as full program implicit print (smashes the digits and characters together)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>97</s> 84 bytes

```apl
5↑∊{¯3↑'0',':',⍨⍕⍵}¨24 60|A⊣⍎¨'⎕IO←1' '⎕IO←0' 'A[1]+←1' 'A[1]-←1'['←→↑'⍳⍞,'←']⊣A←0 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/p@m8KhtgkL1f9NHbRMfdXRVH1pvDGSpG6jrqFup6zzqXfGod@qj3q21h1YYmSiYGdQ4Pupa/Ki379AK9Ud9Uz39gZoN1RXgbAMg2zHaMFYbKg5i64LZ0epA6lHbJJDhj3o3P@qdpwMSUY8FmucI0qlg8L@WC2gOkJ2moK5OCvM/yO0gBDR9MgRxgalJYNEJcDm4KJQzAQmB1HLB9VMDgSwBAA)

Requires `⎕IO←1`

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>109</s> 103 bytes

-6 byte thanks [AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42963/admborkbork)

```
$t=0,0
$args|%{$t[+$i]+=. @{l={$i=0};r={$i=1};u={1};d={119}}.$_}
"{0:00}:{1:00}"-f($t[0]%24),($t[1]%60)
```

Test script:

```
$f = {

$t=0,0
$args|%{$t[+$i]+=. @{l={$i=0};r={$i=1};u={1};d={119}}.$_}
"{0:00}:{1:00}"-f($t[0]%24),($t[1]%60)

}

@(
    ,('02:57',('u','u','r','d','d','d'))
    ,('00:00',('d','r','u','l','u','r','d'))
    ,('23:59',('d','r','r','d'))
    ,('00:01',('l','l','l','l','r','u'))
    ,('23:59',('d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','r','d'))
) | % {
    $e, $c = $_
    $r = &$f @c
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```
True: 02:57
True: 00:00
True: 23:59
True: 00:01
True: 23:59
```

### Explanation

Basic idea is to use a `[hashtable]`, which `keys` are control commands and `values` are scriptblocks. The code execute the scriptblock for each command from arguments.

Comment: You can get rid of `$i=0` by casting your array index like `$t[+$i]` to save some bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzRCoJAEADf/QqRPUg02YsIUhb6DzkiOCvhoDiVHrb99vX0ZWae5vv5DXF6DyGowkxYYwaP@Jr@hmHuKxhdRU1@40AMI6F0cQ8r3UKc6BPtVaSBu2QFY4soLdtNxfF5SA905nQu6y2tMxcsVXXRqF79Cg "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## perl -F// -E, 72 bytes

```
$x=H;/u/?$$x++:/d/?$$x--:($x=/l/?H:M)for@F;printf"%02d:%02d",$H%24,$M%60
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 120 bytes

```
o,i=[0,0],0
for s in list(input()):i=(i+(s=='r')-(s=='l')>=1);o[i]+=(s=='u')-(s=='d')
print'%02d:%02d'%(o[0]%24,o[1]%60)
```

Comment: This looks like a snippet taking input in a variable. As a general rule, we require answers to present either a full program (taking input from program arguments or standard input) or a function (taking input from function parameters).

Comment: Also, won't this run into a wall when an input of, say, `ld` or `rru` causes `i` to leave the range (0,1) and `o[i]` is accessed afterwards?

Comment: @O.O.Balance oh thanks for reminding me that you need function or `unput()`. From requirements I figured that L and R actions will never loop around (i.e. no `LL`)

Comment: @aaaaaa No looping means `lll` isn't the same as `r`. Having `ll` or `rr` is valid input, it's also in the test-cases, see the third one for example.

Comment: This answer currently has an IndexError on the 3rd test case instead of outputting `23:59`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcjBCgIhEIDh@z6FLMg4ZDBJdNjwScSbRAOLI6N76OmNoi4/P197jafUMKd4jok8ZU/LQ9R0w9Xs3Ifj2o7hEDc@RddjBAU8f2cHvEvi/PPj7wVwacp1gKVQtk/AOkmUbbh6SZdsb4RzrkW1rG8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @nit oh snap, apologies

Comment: `s=='d'` is equivalent to `s<'e'`, `s=='u'` is equivalent to `s>'t'`.

Comment: i think i fixed it now @nit

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 186 bytes

```hs
f(0,0)'<'
f t i('^':r)=f(i#t$1)i r
f t i('v':r)=f(i#t$ -1)i r
f t i(x:r)=f t x r
f(h,m)_ _=s h++':':s m
('<'#(h,m))n=(mod(24+n+h)24,m)
(_#(h,m))n=(h,mod(60+n+m)60)
s n=['0'|n<10]++show n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY/LToNAFIb38xQn1GRmMmAGbGucAE@gK5e1EFLlEmFKGMQm6rZrrW/YBykOULEu3HnyJ@fy/WdOJo3U40Oetwl4cNfGhJucYhejGGrICA6wqKgXk2xSn9k0g@obNCcArFO06YEuN92IpGZBQwg9BSljWGChoEBEn5j0iEqPFOt74kyZZCl1pnqGSPgDddZ4zjUu6JxTpEB6C8zxq3RtvmRMpetnkG0RZVL/oYjKGyDlU31bV9cSziGhsDCCwG@axjDBaPzA1c1QDtnV4QeGaTR/hfYtEXqx0H770Wu3334O0ie5I2aXqG93PX0fPR3lgvORHofOhZhdod45qts9@m00vv8f@nXUemsPqziPEtVaq7L8Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>368</s> 355 bytes

```
f=function(){C=as.character
i=ifelse
p=paste0
r=1:10
h=C(0:23);m=C(0:59)
h[r]=p(0,h[r])
m[r]=p(0,m[r])
x=y=z=1
while(T){print(p(h[x],":",m[y]))
v=1
n="[UDLRS]"
while(!grepl(n,v))v=toupper(readline(n))
if(v=="L")z=1 else if(v=="R")z=0
if(v=="S")T=F
if(v=="U")if(z)x=i(x==24,1,x+1)else y=i(y==60,1,y+1)
if(v=="D")if(z)x=i(x==1,24,x-1)else y=i(y==1,60,y-1)}}
```

Definitely not the best approach, but works.

Functionality: Run function, type each letter to (in/de)crease or move left/right, typing "s" ends the "game". The catch is that it will accept one and only one letter at a time.

**-13 bytes** Consolidated some values into one row, overwrote T as F instead of using break, found several spaces to eliminate, and a string stored in a variable instead

```
f=function(){C=as.character                             # Abbreviate functions
i=ifelse
p=paste0
r=1:10                                                  # Initialize and format values
h=C(0:23);m=C(0:59)
h[r]=p(0,h[r])
m[r]=p(0,m[r])
x=y=z=1
while(T){print(p(h[x],":",m[y]))                        # Begin while loop and print time
v=1                                                     # Initial value reset each iteration to retrieve a new direction
n="[UDLRS]"                                             # Used for verification and request
while(!grepl(n,v))v=toupper(readline(n))                # Will only accept proper directions or stopping rule
if(v=="L")z=1 else if(v=="R")z=0                        # Evaluate for hour or minute
if(v=="S")T=F                                           # Stopping rule, overwrite True to False
if(v=="U")if(z)x=i(x==24,1,x+1)else y=i(y==60,1,y+1)    # Rules for Up
if(v=="D")if(z)x=i(x==1,24,x-1)else y=i(y==1,60,y-1)}}  # Rules for Down
```

I am also editing an alternate format to accept an R string and/or vector, will post next week.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 123 bytes

```
@L
B=BUTTON(2)D=(B==1)-(B==2)S=S+!S*(B>7)-S*(B==4)H=(H+D*!S+24)MOD 24WAIT
M=(M+D*S+60)MOD 60?FORMAT$("%02D:%02D",H,M)GOTO@L
```

`BUTTON()` returns an integer where each bit represents a button

```
1 = up
2 = down
4 = left
8 = right
...
```

`BUTTON(2)` returns only the buttons that were just pressed (not being held)

`WAIT` is required because `BUTTON` only updates once per frame (1/60 of a second). Otherwise the same button press would be detected multiple times.

This can definitely be shorter

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 32 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'l¡'rδ¡0ζć‚R€S„0uskOŽ9¦2ä%T‰J':ý
```

Uses `udlr` for the directions, but could also use `^v<>` for the same byte-count (the characters `↑↓←→` are not part of 05AB1E's codepage, so using those would increase the byte-count by a lot, since the encoding should be changed).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9vc2FiaWX//ydswqEncs60wqEwzrbEh@KAmlLigqxT4oCeMHVza0/FvTnCpjLDpCVU4oCwSic6w73//2xsbHJ1cnVsZGRk) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf/WcQwvVi85tObTQ4Ny2I@2PGmYFPWpaE/yoYZ5BaXG2/9G9loeWGR1eohryqGGDl7rV4b3/df6XlhalpKRwpRSV5gBZQBpI5ABBUSlXCi4AVALRlpNSBBbIKQUCrqKiHAjMAWEwgrKhfKChQGOhdA5QHwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'l¡          '# Split the (implicit) input on "l"
              #  i.e. "lllrurulddd" → ["","","","ruru","ddd"]
     δ        # Map each item to:
   'r ¡      '#  Split the item on "r"
              #   → [[""],[""],[""],["","u","u"],["ddd"]]
       0ζ     # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns, with 0 as filler
              #  → [["","","","","ddd"],[0,0,0,"u",0],[0,0,0,"u",0]]
ć             # Head extracted: pop and push the remainder and head-item to the stack
              #  → [[0,0,0,"u",0],[0,0,0,"u",0]] and ["","","","","ddd"]
 ‚R           # Pair the head and remainder back together, and reverse the pair
              # (so the remainder portion is basically wrapped in a list now)
              #  → [["","","","","ddd"],[[0,0,0,"u",0],[0,0,0,"u",0]]]
   €S         # Convert each item to a list of characters
              # (implicitly flattens and removes empty strings)
              #  → [["d","d","d"],[0,0,0,"u",0,0,0,0,"u",0]]
      „0usk   # Index each character into the string "0u"
              # (0 remains 0; "u" becomes 1; "d" becomes -1 since it's not in this string)
              #  → [[-1,-1,-1],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
           O  # Then take the sum of each inner list
              #  → [-3,2]
Ž9¦           # Push compressed integer 2460
   2ä         # Split into two parts: [24,60]
     %        # Modulo the two lists
              #  → [21,2]
      T‰      # Divmod each with 10
              #  → [[2,1],[0,2]]
        J     # Join each inner list together
              #  → ["21","02"]
         ':ý '# Join the list with ":" delimiter
              #  → "21:02"
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž9¦` is `2460`.